# Question about meaning of "Legoland"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, metaphors

While surfing the internet, I came across this sentence and I wonder what it really means:

> We Americans sometimes seem to view Canada as a kind of Legoland version of our own country ...

I searched the web and found meaning of **Legoland** in the web page below.

But my real problem is the meaning of the expression **square edges** . 
Could you simplify the meaning of  both **legoland** and **square edges**, please?

> slang - A place characterised by square edges and extreme regularity.1997, Mark McCrum, No worries: a journey through Australia ...three hundred yards back from that, behind a legoland of hotels and apartment blocks... 
>   Source: http://www.wordsense.eu/Legoland/

Comment: Are you familiar with [these Lego toys](http://static.productreview.com.au/pr.products/lego-basic-bricks-large_4f4cc58913755.jpg)? If not, that picture might help the meaning come into focus.

Comment: @user5036 The meaning of Legoland in US popular culture is probably slightly different than that of European culture (Europe has had Legoland theme parks for decades); I would have associated regular, square edged object with the phrase "a Lego version" but not "a Legoland version"...

Answer (score 6):

Legoland is an amusement park, one of whose prime attractions is the intricate scale models of real-world landscapes and landmarks.

[image: Legoland California: Miniland USA]

In this context, calling Canada a "Legoland" version of America is a derisive metaphor, saying that Canada is just a scaled-down reproduction of the USA.  In many ways, the two countries share similar cultures and institutions, but nearly everything in Canada is on a smaller scale due to its much lower population.

I don't think that the square edges are an important part of the metaphor, other than the fact that a model built of square blocks is necessarily a low-resolution model.

Answer (score 2):

The full quote is:

> We Americans sometimes seem to view Canada as a kind of Legoland version of our own country — one in which we see pretty much our own values, worldview, language, and culture, albeit not with the perfect clarity one might find in, say, a mirror or a well-executed still life painting.

Legoland is a place dedicated to Lego toys. So I think that in this context, Legoland would be a synonym of *toy version*, *decaffeinated version* or *imitation* ( with a slight negative connotation).

> We Americans sometimes seem to view Canada as a *toy version* version of our own country

The main components of Lego are plastic blocks, so the author emphasizes that the  edges of the blocks are straight (mathematically *square edge* doesn't make sense) :

[image]

Comment: +1 I'd like to add that using *square* as an adjective doesn't have to always mean a regular quadrilateral. For example, some people can have a square jaw or square shoulders.

Answer (score 1):

*Square* means "in the shape of a square", but it can also refer to 90 degree angles, which are commonly called *right angles*.

*Square edges* means two or more edges that are at right angles to each other.

The tool below is called a square because it is used for making things square. (That is, it is used for making right angles.)

[image]

If you were making a box out of wood, you could use that tool to make sure that all the corners were square.